# Spreadsheet Libreoffice calc - pivot table - How to group chuncks of time seperated by a minimum of 30 mins

Tags: pivot-table, formula, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

I have a report in libreoffice calc which contains 2 sheets.
The first one is a data sheet and the second one is a "report" sheet (with pivot tables).

In the first data sheet, there are 3 important columns, the first column has dates, the second column has time stamps and the third column has a product code called "Type".

I'm trying to create a pivot table that would automatically show per date, per "chuncks of time" seperated by a minimum of 30 mins, the count of type per type.

The trouble comes from how to create the chunks of time. There needs to be at least a 30 mins between 2 time stamp to qualify as a chunck of time.

for example, Data sheet:

| Date | Time | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17.01.22 | 9:13 | 12 |
| 17.01.22 | 9:14 | 12 |
| 17.01.22 | 9:15 | 17 |
| 17.01.22 | 9:20 | 17 |
| 17.01.22 | 9:22 | 17 |
| 17.01.22 | 12:28 | 17 |
| 17.01.22 | 12:42 | 17 |
| 17.01.22 | 15:16 | 17 |
| 17.01.22 | 15:42 | 17 |
| 17.01.22 | 15:55 | 13 |
| 17.01.22 | 15:58 | 13 |

The end result in a pivot table should be:

| Date | Time-Frame | Type | Count-Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17.01.22 | 9:13-9:22 | 12 | 2 |
| 17.01.22 | 9:13-9:22 | 17 | 3 |
| 17.01.22 | 12:28-12:42 | 17 | 2 |
| 17.01.22 | 15:16-15:58 | 17 | 2 |
| 17.01.22 | 15:16-15:58 | 13 | 2 |

or

| Date | Time-Frame | Type | Count-Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17.01.22 | 9:13-9:22 | 12 | 2 |
|  |  | 17 | 3 |
| 17.01.22 | 12:28-12:42 | 17 | 2 |
| 17.01.22 | 15:16-15:58 | 17 | 2 |
|  |  | 13 | 2 |

Let me know if you have any question.
And thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I went this route:
https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/how-to-group-chuncks-of-time-seperated-by-a-minimum-of-30-mins-pivot-table/74936

Which creates a helper column with this forumla:
in C2:=IF((N(A2)+N(B2)-N(A1)-N(B1))>(1/48);N(C1)+1;N(C1)

Then end result is:

| Date | Time | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17.01.22 | 9:13 | 1 |
| 17.01.22 | 9:14 | 1 |
| 17.01.22 | 9:15 | 1 |
| 17.01.22 | 9:20 | 1 |
| 17.01.22 | 9:22 | 1 |
| 17.01.22 | 12:28 | 2 |
| 17.01.22 | 12:42 | 2 |
| 17.01.22 | 15:16 | 3 |
| 17.01.22 | 15:42 | 3 |
| 17.01.22 | 15:55 | 3 |
| 17.01.22 | 15:58 | 3 |